# How to keep selected checkbox row when we filter the rowData in material UI Datagrid even when its not present in the filtered rowData

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

In the material UI Datagrid component with prop `checkboxSelection` set to `true`, I want to implement a search/filter functionality so that my checked/selected rows are not lost after I filter the rowData based on my search query.

Right now what happens is that, when I filter the rows, the previously selected rows are lost due to them not being present in the filtered rowData.

I have created a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/controlledselectiongrid-material-demo-forked-ikd7bf?file=/demo.js) depicting the same and a possible solution which I have commented but it ends up in an infinite render loop react error.

Any help/ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `Controlled Row Selection` with prop `keepNonExistentRowsSelected` as described [here](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/row-selection/#usage-with-server-side-pagination)

```
<DataGrid
  checkboxSelection
  keepNonExistentRowsSelected
  onRowSelectionModelChange={(newRowSelectionModel) => {
    setRowSelectionModel(newRowSelectionModel);
  }}
  rowSelectionModel={rowSelectionModel}
  {...data}
/>
```